# Prove that the given triangle has AB = AC

Tags: geometry

In $∆ABC$ let $D$ be a point on segment $BC$ such that $AB + BD = AC + CD$. Suppose that the points $B$, $C$ and the centroids of $∆ACD$ and $∆ABD$ lie on a circle . Prove that $AB = AC$.[image]

【I have proved till now that $G_1G_2$ is parallel to $BC$ (using cyclic quadrilateral and similar triangles and the property that centroid divides median in 2:1 ratio) and hence $∆EBC$ is an isosceles triangle and $BG_1G_2C$ is an isosceles trapezium (since it is a cyclic trapezium). I am trying to prove that $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$ somehow, but I cannot progress after this.
If you can help me proceed from here it would be of great help.】

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $\triangle EBC$ is isosceles and $EB=EC$. Notice that $EB$ and $EC$ are medians in $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$, respectively. The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)#Formulas_involving_the_medians%27_lengths) for the length of the medians gives us
$$BE^2=\frac 14\left(2AB^2+2BD^2-AD^2\right) \\
CE^2=\frac 14\left(2AC^2+2CD^2-AD^2\right) $$
Since $BE^2=CE^2$, we obtain
$$AB^2+BD^2=AC^2+CD^2 \tag{1} $$
Then substitute $AB=AC+CD-BD$ in $(1)$ to obtain
$$BD(BD-CD)=AC(BD-CD) $$
So either $BD=CD$ (what we need) or $BD=AC$. If $BD=AC$, from the given equality you get $CD=AB$. Hence $BD+CD=AB+AC\Rightarrow BC=AB+AC$. This is a contradiction with the triangle inequality.